# Rails - Suddenly, redirect_to always gives error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All of a sudden, any and all `redirect_to` calls on my Rails app are returning this `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error. I can't for the life of me identify the reason.

Even simple calls like

```
def show
   redirect_to root_path
end

# routes
root to: "home#index"
```

... are erroing with no indication whatsoever in the backtrace, at least that I can pinpoint.

I've already tried, based on other questions answered here on SO:

- Update turbolinks gem
- Update all gems
- Remove active_admin
- Remove devise
- Remove pundit
- Call path helper, url helper, absolute path, relative path, pass arguments, pass no arguments
- Updating actionpack
- Updating Rails

In all other answers the problem seems to be old gems or typos, but in my case ALL of them simply stopped working, even the ones that have been fine for months and untouched.

The trace is always exactly the same, from anywhere in the app:

```
    Redirected to
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 177ms

    ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:76:in `redirect_to'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:57:in `redirect_to'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:61:in `block in redirect_to'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:60:in `redirect_to'
      app/controllers/ads_controller.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in create'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:216:in `respond_to'
      app/controllers/ads_controller.rb:92:in `create'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
      activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
      actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
      omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
      omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      bullet (5.0.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
      puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
      puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
      puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
      puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Going through Rails source of this version, this is the method giving the trouble:

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) #:doc:
  raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") unless options
  raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to a parameter hash!") if options.is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
  raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body
  self.status        = _extract_redirect_to_status(options, response_status)
  self.location      = _compute_redirect_to_location(request, options)
  self.response_body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
end
```

From my limited knowledge, I have three suspects:

1. HAML, since the call is for ERB in the last line, the one in the backtrace (but I don't feel it's here)
2. Something in the request stopped being sent by some code, giving probles in the `location` var.
3. Something in flash messages? I have Toasts installed but it has been working perfectly fine for weeks, and the error happens even when no flash message is set. This is the main suspect.

But how do I solve or debug this with more details?

**EDIT: Add redirect_to line from backtrace**
The line in question giving the error in this particular case is

```
if @ad.save
  UserMailer.admin_event_email('create_ad', @ad).deliver_later
  redirect_to ad_created_path, success: I18n.t('The ad is poster and a moderator will aprove it shortly')
end
```

But it ALWAYS happens at the redirect_to line.

Comment: What is located on line `app/controllers/ads_controller.rb:92:in 'create'` ? Can you paste that code?

Comment: I've added to the question. It is just the redirect_to call. It always fails at the call.

Comment: I have updated the answer, could you check especially what `ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)` returns and what is the value of `location`

Comment: Hi! I just found out some of the reason. It is because I was including ApplicationHelper in the controller. In all controllers where I did this, the error would ocorr. I just replaced the method calls with view_context.method call and it solved the issued. I'll prepare an answer and continue to investigate the helper that caused it. Thanks very much for the help and the interest in the question!

Comment: You welcome :) I am glad you have found the solution at the end, which is the most important thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
redirect_to ad_created_path, success: I18n.t('The ad is poster and a moderator will aprove it shortly')
```

to:

```
redirect_to ad_created_path, :flash => { success: I18n.t('The ad is poster and a moderator will aprove it shortly') }
```

**Edit**:

Update the turbo-links to verison `2.5.3`

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.3'
```

**Edit 2:**

Put a breakpoint at this line:

```
=> 76:       byebug
=> 77:       self.response_body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

And what is the result of `"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"` ?

Comment: Tried and didn't work, unfortunately. Also tried calling flash[:success] = '...' before the redirect, removing the flash completely but it will still error...

Comment: Heh, I know might be guessing what you have already tried, but who knows, maybe you have missed something, some small detail :)

Comment: Oh no, I tried after you suggested. I even copied pasted to make sure I wasn't mispelling anything. Thanks for trying! I really appreciate it!

Comment: hm, stupid question - when you update the gem you put it into gem file and run `bundle install`, or you do `bundle gem update turbolinks`?

Answer (score 0):

So, after long hours, I found at least the partial culprit: **including  ApplicationHelper** into the controller.

In all controllers where ApplicationHelper was included, this error would occur. For now, this is what I did:

- Removed ApplicationHelper from controllers
- Changed calls to helper methods to `view_context.my_helper` in the controller

Now I'll try to find which helper was causing the issue and will update this answer if and when I find it.